# Fitting codes in a Latex Code block

Tags: listings, code

```
    \usepackage{listings}           
    \begin{document}

\lstset{language=Java}        

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]  

             PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
             String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
             doc.close();
             return new Indexitem((long)file.getName().hashCode(), file.getName(), content);

\end{lstlisting}
    \end{document}
```

Considering the above code, my question is how to fit the code into its block? Assuming we are using a double-column template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,breakatwhitespace,gobble=10` is an alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}           
\begin{document}

\lstset{language=Java}        
%\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,gobble=14,basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily]
%\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,breaklines,breakatwhitespace,gobble=10]
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single,breaklines]

             PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
             String content = new PDFTextStripper().getText(doc);
             doc.close();
             return new Indexitem((long)file.getName().hashCode(), file.getName(), content);

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: but `breaklines` makes it ugly. I want each code to be represented in one individual line Moreover, the block looks ugly, the code has not equal spaces from all 4 corners.

Comment: makes no real sense. However, see edited answer with `gobble=14,...`

Comment: My question makes no real sense? 
But `gobble=14,basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily` looks perfect. However it misses the some characters of each line. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Ok, I set `globe=5` and things looks nice now. Thank you :)